# Navigation Menu dropping down its list below a floated image and not just below itself

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation menu which is dropping down its list below a left floated logo in Mobile Responsive Mode. This is happening possibly due to the logo's float property. How can i make the dropdown appear just below the menu button. Click on menu atthis fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/AwesomeHat/rseuct2x/ to see.

HTML Code-

```
<div id="header">
<img src="http://www.operadevelopers.com/images/logo.png" class="logo" />
<div id="social">
<a href="https://www.wikipedia.org" class="icon-button wikipedia"><i class="fa fa-wikipedia-w" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com" class="icon-button linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="icon-button google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="icon-button twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="icon-button facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
<!--Navigation Bar-->
<nav>
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Menu &#x2630;</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Whats New</a>
<ul class="hidden">
<li><a href="#">Just Launched</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Launching Soon</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Completed Projects</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Referral</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Buyers Section</a>
<ul class="hidden">
<li><a href="#">EMI Calculator</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Apply For Loan</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Make an Enquiry</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS Code -

```
#header {
background: black;
width: 100%;
height: 210px;
min-height: 100%;
}
.logo {
float: left;
padding-left: 5%;
padding-top: 25px;
}
.icon-button {
color: white;
border: 0px;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 1.0rem;
line-height: 1.7rem;
margin: 1px;
text-align: center;
width: 1.7rem;
margin-top: 60px;
float: right;
overflow: hidden;
}
.facebook {
background-color: #3B5998;
}
.twitter {
background-color: #4099ff;
}
.google-plus {
background-color: #db5a3c;
}
.linkedin {
background-color: #007fb1;
}
.wikipedia {
background-color: white;
overflow: hidden;
color: black;
margin-right: 100px;
}
.icon-button:hover {
background-color: rgba(165,219,89,1);
transition: 1s;
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
nav ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin-top: 170px;
padding:0;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
z-index: 20000;
}
nav ul li {
display:inline-block;
float: left;
width: 14.2857%; /* fallback for non-calc() browsers */
width: calc(100% / 7);
}
nav ul li a {
display:block;
min-width:140px;
height: 40px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 40px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #fff;
background: #161616;
text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
color: rgb(165,219,89);
}
nav ul li:hover ul a {
color: #fff;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
}
nav ul li:hover ul a:hover {
color: rgb(165,219,89);
}
nav ul li ul {
margin-top: 0px;
display: none;
}
nav ul li ul li {
display: block;
float: none;
width: 200px;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
width: auto;
min-width: 100px;
padding: 0 20px;
}
nav ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
display: block;
}
.show-menu {
float: right;
width: 70px;
height: 25px;
margin-top: 90px;
margin-right: -100px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
background: blue;
text-align: center;
display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]{
display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
.logo {
padding-left: 10%;
}
.icon-button {
font-size: 0.8rem;
line-height: 1.5rem;
width: 1.5rem;
margin-top: 60px;
}
.wikipedia {
margin-right: 7%;
}
nav ul {
position: relative;
margin-top: 0;
float: right;
display: none;
}
nav ul li, li a {
width: 90%;
}
nav ul li ul {
margin-top: 0px;
display: block;
}
nav ul li ul li {
width: 90%;
}
.show-menu {
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could only look fast over your Code, but i think your Menu Button is always at the same Position.

So you can add a margin-top tag to your css.

```
#menu {
   margin-top: -37px;
}
```

At my Computer, this works fine. But you have to try it on mobile device.

Comment: When you click Menu the dropdown is occuring much below the Menu button. I want it to start right below Menu button. Can you suggest another way?

Comment: I think, the "nav" must have a negative margin-top so that it will start below the button. Please add my Code, and then Show me, what happens.

Comment: Forgot to come back and report, margin-top: -37px solved the problem. Can't believe something so simple i missed. Thanks alot!

Comment: It would be nice, if you mark it at the right answer ;) Thx

Comment: Done. Also thanks to Rasmus Glenvig for solving part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

try below code, i think this can helpful for you.

```css
#header {
 background: black;
 width: 100%;
 height: 210px;
 min-height: 100%;
}
.logo {
 float: left;
 padding-left: 5%;
 padding-top: 25px;
}
.icon-button {
    color: white;
 border: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.0rem;
 line-height: 1.7rem;
    margin: 1px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 1.7rem;
 margin-top: 60px;
 float: right;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.facebook {
  background-color: #3B5998;
}
.twitter {
  background-color: #4099ff;
}
.google-plus {
  background-color: #db5a3c;
}
.linkedin {
  background-color: #007fb1;
}
.wikipedia {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
.icon-button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(165,219,89,1);
  transition: 1s;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
nav ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin-top: 170px;
 padding:0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 75%;
 z-index: 20000;
}
nav ul li {
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
 width: 14.2857%; /* fallback for non-calc() browsers */
    width: calc(100% / 7);
}
nav ul li a {
 display:block;
 min-width:140px;
 height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 40px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 background: #161616;
 text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
 color: rgb(165,219,89);
}
nav ul li:hover ul a {
 color: #fff;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
}
nav ul li:hover ul a:hover {
 color: rgb(165,219,89);
}
nav ul li ul {
 margin-top: 0px;
 display: none;
}
nav ul li ul li {
 display: block;
 float: none;
 width: 200px;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
width: auto;
min-width: 100px;
padding: 0 20px;
}
nav ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
 display: block;
}
.show-menu {
 float: right;
    width: 70px;
    height: 25px;
 margin-top: 90px;
 margin-right: -100px;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 background: blue;
 text-align: center;
 display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
.logo {
 padding-left: 10%;
}
.icon-button {
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 line-height: 1.5rem;
 width: 1.5rem;
 margin-top: 60px;
}
.wikipedia {
  margin-right: 7%;
}
nav ul {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 0;
    float: right;
 display: none;
}
nav ul li, li a {
  width: 90%;
 }
nav ul li ul {
 margin-top: 0px;
 display: block;
}
nav ul li ul li {
 width: 90%;
}
 .show-menu {
  display:block;
 }
  nav ul li ul li {
  width: 100%;
}
.hidden {
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul li, li a {
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
<img src="http://www.operadevelopers.com/images/logo.png" class="logo" />
<div id="social">
<a href="https://www.wikipedia.org" class="icon-button wikipedia"><i class="fa fa-wikipedia-w" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com" class="icon-button linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="icon-button google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="icon-button twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="icon-button facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
<!--Navigation Bar-->
<nav>
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Menu &#x2630;</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Whats New</a>
<ul class="hidden">
<li><a href="#">Just Launched</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Launching Soon</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Completed Projects</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Referral</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Buyers Section</a>
<ul class="hidden">
<li><a href="#">EMI Calculator</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Apply For Loan</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Make an Enquiry</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but If you click menu it is dropping it much below the Menu button. I want it to start right below the menu button. Any other possibilities?

Comment: @AwesomeHat i have updated my answer. please you can check, i thibk you have need this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wanted to bring it up. According to Marcel's answer i changed margin top to -37px and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `nav ul li` to be `float: left;`, so if you change that to `float: right;` like so:

```css
#header {
 background: black;
 width: 100%;
 height: 210px;
 min-height: 100%;
}
.logo {
 float: left;
 padding-left: 5%;
 padding-top: 25px;
}
.icon-button {
    color: white;
 border: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.0rem;
 line-height: 1.7rem;
    margin: 1px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 1.7rem;
 margin-top: 60px;
 float: right;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.facebook {
  background-color: #3B5998;
}
.twitter {
  background-color: #4099ff;
}
.google-plus {
  background-color: #db5a3c;
}
.linkedin {
  background-color: #007fb1;
}
.wikipedia {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
.icon-button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(165,219,89,1);
  transition: 1s;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
nav ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin-top: 170px;
 padding:0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 20000;
}
nav ul li {
 display:inline-block;
 float: right;
 width: 14.2857%; /* fallback for non-calc() browsers */
    width: calc(100% / 7);
}
nav ul li a {
 display:block;
 min-width:140px;
 height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 40px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 background: #161616;
 text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
 color: rgb(165,219,89);
}
nav ul li:hover ul a {
 color: #fff;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
}
nav ul li:hover ul a:hover {
 color: rgb(165,219,89);
}
nav ul li ul {
 margin-top: 0px;
 display: none;
}
nav ul li ul li {
 display: block;
 float: none;
 width: 200px;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
width: auto;
min-width: 100px;
padding: 0 20px;
}
nav ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
 display: block;
}
.show-menu {
 float: right;
    width: 70px;
    height: 25px;
 margin-top: 90px;
 margin-right: -100px;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 background: blue;
 text-align: center;
 display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
.logo {
 padding-left: 10%;
}
.icon-button {
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 line-height: 1.5rem;
 width: 1.5rem;
 margin-top: 60px;
}
.wikipedia {
  margin-right: 7%;
}
nav ul {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 0;
    float: right;
 display: none;
}
nav ul li, li a {
  width: 90%;
 }
nav ul li ul {
 margin-top: 0px;
 display: block;
}
nav ul li ul li {
 width: 90%;
}
 .show-menu {
  display:block;
 }
```

```html
<div id="header">
<img src="http://www.operadevelopers.com/images/logo.png" class="logo" />
<div id="social">
<a href="https://www.wikipedia.org" class="icon-button wikipedia"><i class="fa fa-wikipedia-w" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com" class="icon-button linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="icon-button google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="icon-button twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="icon-button facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
<!--Navigation Bar-->
<nav>
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Menu &#x2630;</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Whats New</a>
<ul class="hidden">
<li><a href="#">Just Launched</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Launching Soon</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Completed Projects</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Referral</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Buyers Section</a>
<ul class="hidden">
<li><a href="#">EMI Calculator</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Apply For Loan</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Make an Enquiry</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that's a better idea, than mine ;)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but If you click menu it is dropping it much below the Menu button. I want it to start right below the menu button superimposing itself over the logo image.